# How to include HTML tags in amphtml

Tags: html, validation, amp-html

This is my script tag when trying to add amp to it, validator says script tags are not allowed except in some cases.Can someone help me out please.

```
<script >
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
      ga('create', 'UA-71734474-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');

    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in amp, analytics are surrounded by extra tags

```
<amp-analytics type="googleanalytics" id="analytics1">
<script>

</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

but google analytics do not generally take the same format

its's usually something like this

```
"vars": {
    "account": "UA-XXXXX-Y" //your ga number
  },
  "triggers": {
    "trackPageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    }
  }
```

See the [amp developers page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/amp-analytics/) for more info

Comment: Thank you Rachel but my script in not something that is in json format

Comment: <script >
          (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
          (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
          m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
          })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
          ga('create', 'UA-71734474-1', 'auto');
          ga('send', 'pageview');

        </script>

Comment: @nlr_p you still need the surrounding tags

Comment: @nlr_p have you included the required script for analytics? <script async custom-element="amp-analytics"
    src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>

Comment: @nlr_p if you have no luck with google, there are loads of other analytic tools you can use with amp-html, look at https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/extended/amp-analytics.html

Comment: The post by you is not opening please post again

Comment: https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js put script async tags around it as described

Comment: flag 
@nlr_p have you included the required script for analytics? <script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></…; – Rachel Gallen 45 mins ago